# Encrypted logical channel in Host Card Emulation

Tags: android, cryptography, nfc, apdu, hce

HCE implementations only support a single logical channel and it is by default not encrypted.

Does anyone know, is it possible to establish a encrypted logical channel in HCE or any other way to make host card emulation more secure.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly give the reason for minus points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that Android HCE typically only supports the basic logical channel. I guess support for multiple logical channels would be difficult to implement in the routing procedure.

However, encryption of the communication is not really influenced by the lack of additional logical channels. You could, for instance, use the secure messaging structures and the authentication commands defined in ISO/IEC 7816-4 to establish encrypted and secured communication over the basic logical channel. Similarly you could define your own application-specific security protocol.